# How can i added default header for DELETE in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, rest, http

This is working fine in angular js

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
$http.defaults.headers.put['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
$http.defaults.headers.patch['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
```

But this is not working

```
$http.defaults.headers.delete['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) document, Angular only have three default headers configuration: common, put and post.

> To add headers for an HTTP method other than POST or PUT, simply add a new object with the lowercased HTTP method name as the key

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }.
```

So in your case,

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = { 'X-CSRFToken' : $cookies['csrftoken'] }.
```

Comment: do i need to use $http or $$httpProvider

Comment: both $http and $httpProvider are Okay